# multi level combinational knapsack

Tags: sql, r, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have large set of combinations of tables used in data warehouse queries.

**Example:**

```
QueryID    Table
--------   ------
1          t1
1          t2
1          t3
--------------
2          t1
2          t3
--------------
3          t4
3          t2
--------------
4          t2
4          t3
4          t4
--------------
5          t3
5          t1
```

...and more.... (around thousands of such combinations).
My current analysis involves finding patterns out of this like most frequently used together tables etc. My next analysis point is to find maximum number of queries that can be run by using minimum number of tables and also taking the tables' sizes into consideration.

For example from the above data, we can have minimum of 2 queries run by using three tables combination (t1,t2,t3) and (t1,t3) and (t2,t3,t4) etc.... For example if the sizes of the tables are

```
table    size
-----    -----
t1        20 GB
t2        40 GB
t3        10 GB
t4        50 GB
```

Then

1. (t1,t2,t3) together sized 70 GB can run three queries
2. (t1,t3) together sized 30 GB can run two queries
3. (t2,t3,t4) together sized 100 GB can run two queries

Out of these (t1,t3) is the best combination of tables with minimum size and count that can run two queries. I am trying multiple approaches with SQL, Excel, R to come up with dynamic solution which can take up parameters like number of queries you want to run, maximum size of the tables combination you want to tolerate for etc. Any best approaches or suggestions here will be appreciated.

Update:

The queries will need all of its participating tables to be available to run. So we cannot say t1 alone will satisfy requirement of two queries or t2 alone can satisfy requirements of 3 queries.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me how you are calculating the number of queries for a group of tables.  I can see that `t1` has two queries, `t2` has three queries, and `t3` has three queries.  How do you calculate the number of queries from the combination of tables `t1`, `t2`, and `t3`?

```
# the data that you posted
quer <- structure(list(QueryID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
    Table = c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t1", "t3", "t4", "t2", "t2", "t3", "t4")), 
    .Names = c("QueryID", "Table"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
size <- structure(list(Table = c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"), 
    GB = c(20L, 40L, 10L, 50L)), .Names = c("Table", "GB"), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

# perhaps a helpful way to reorganize your query data
both <- merge(quer, size)
size2 <- tapply(both$GB, list(both$QueryID, both$Table), mean)
size2
  t1 t2 t3 t4
1 20 40 10 NA
2 20 NA 10 NA
3 NA 40 NA 50
4 NA 40 10 50

apply(size2, 1, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
  1   2   3   4 
 70  30  90 100
```

Comment: The queries will need all of its participating tables to be available to run. So we cannot say t1 alone will satisfy requirement of two queries or t2 alone can satisfy requirements of 3 qureies. Trouble with rearranging the data is the number of tables parameter is it does not provide feature to calculate smallest possible table sizes combination to come out.

Comment: I edited my answer with another way to reorg your data.  See if that helps.  Also, I think I understand your query count, but then, how do you get TWO queries for tables `t1` and `t3` combined?

Comment: Oops... Missed it. Sorry. Modifying it.

Comment: Added one more query. Looking into your answer now.

Comment: Apologies if I did not get it Jean. I am having difficulty in understanding how to represent the above data structure to know if tables t1 and t3 will be able to get us two queries here? Or t1,t2,t3 will get us three queries. From above I can get cumulative sum of tables' sizes for each query.

Comment: If you define a vector listing the table combination that you are interested in, `withtables <- c(1, 3)`, then you can use this statement to calculate the number of queries, `sum(apply(is.na(size2[, -withtables]), 1, all))`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, you want the minimum size needed for x number of queries to be run

```
library(data.table)

#datasets borrowed from @androboy s answer (removed special character for code formatting to work)
quer <- structure(list(QueryID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
                       Table = c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t1", "t3", "t4", "t2", "t2", "t3", "t4")), 
                  .Names = c("QueryID", "Table"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
size <- structure(list(Table = c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"), 
                       GB = c(20L, 40L, 10L, 50L)), .Names = c("Table", "GB"), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

quer <- data.table(quer)
size <- data.table(size)
# number of queries to run
queries <- 2

# creating unique combinations of two queries each-------------------
querylist <- vector(mode="list",length=queries)
for(i in seq(queries))
{
  querylist[[i]]<-unique(quer$QueryID)
}
qdf <- (expand.grid(querylist))
# removing rows with same query counted twice
if ( queries > 1)
{
  test <- apply(
    t(combn(seq(queries),2)),
    1,
    function(x)
    {
      (qdf[,x[1]] != qdf[,x[2]])
    }
  )

  qdf <- qdf[rowSums(test) == (queries-1),]
}

qdf <- data.table(qdf)
# checking tablesizes needed to run this combination-------------------
qdf[,tablesneeded := '']
qdf[,sizeneeded := as.integer(NA)]

setkeyv(quer,'QueryID')
setkeyv(size,'Table')

for( i in seq(nrow(qdf)))
{
  Tables <- quer[data.table(V1 =unlist(qdf[i,grep(colnames(qdf), pattern = "Var", value = TRUE), with = FALSE]))[,keyby = 'V1']][,unique(Table)]

  qdf[i, tablesneeded := paste(Tables,collapse = ',')]

  qdf[i, sizeneeded := as.integer(sum(size[data.table(V1 = Tables)[, keyby = 'V1']][,GB], na.rm = TRUE))]

}

# lowest size option for current number of queries-----------------------
qdf[which.min(sizeneeded)]
```

Comment: Awesome.. This looks like is working. Need to test more. However, one small doubt, will this method scale for large number of query and table combinations. Some thing like 20000 queries with around 500 unique tables used in them? I am not sure if there will be any issues with the memory available.

Comment: I think this will be highly dependent on the value of `queries`. So if you're checking for a small number of combinations, I think it should be okay. I would also suggest using `data.table`s instead of `data.frame`s because they are much faster and efficient.

Comment: In case of the above solution not scaling, can I some how make this run in a distributed fashion with may be R running on Hadoop or any similar program running on Hadoop. Do you think I should do that or will R itself be able to run this optimally?

Comment: There are some parallel processing packages but I haven't used them myself so I can't help much, I'm afraid. Off the top of my head, Google `snow` and `mclapply`. But before all that, did you try `data.table`?

Comment: I tried putting in data.table and was having trouble with Error in quer[quer$QueryID %in% unlist(qdf[i, ]), "Table"] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions.. Looking further..

Comment: Made some edits. There might be more you can do to make it faster but this should give you a start. Did you try the data.frame solution on your problem though? What were the runtimes for that?

Answer (score 0):

You should go for brute force for all combination of tables within admissible size and get one with max queries covered, it will generate all subsets hence `O(2^N*N)`. If brute is not feasible then i am afraid your problem is harder than knapsack problem at least and there is no polynomial time solution for it. Another case is where a good solution will do for you then greedy knapsack or use of genetic algorithm to get good feasible solution

Comment: I have that solution already in place. But was looking for any algo/ approach which may reduce the maximum combinations needed to be scanned.

Comment: It is 50 tables initially but once scalable, we are planning to run it through 1600 tables.

Comment: Then i am afraid brute force or any other solution which gets optimal will be infeasible so use genetic algorithm to get good solutions in reasonable time.

Comment: Thanks Vikram. I haven't used genetic algo before, but found an example implementation here... http://www.r-bloggers.com/genetic-algorithms-a-simple-r-example/ Do you have any other examples around which can help in my scenario?

Comment: @androboy Very first step towards genetic algorithm solution is that imagining what your gene would be? In your case it is simple it will be string of (0,1) of length n where 0 means table is not included in the set else if 1 then included.

Comment: @androboy Then cost function : which is the maximum unique queries supported by the set of tables included in the subset. Beware to reject sets that are above the feasible total table sizes.

Comment: @androboy Mutation: Try to remove one table and add any other one .

Comment: @androboy Using all points you will be able to construct a good genetic solution to your problem , then we can do optimization on it.